# Creating a Javascript drop down for individual users

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that works but only for the first row. Even if you click on the 3rd button it references the top button's information and position. How do I tell Javascript that the drop-down should be based on an individual user? (in this example there are 3 users identified by their ids: 2160, 3550, and 5520)

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<p>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="1-2160.html">1</a>
    <a href="2-2160.html">2</a>
    <a href="3-2160.html">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</p>

<p>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="1-3550.html">1</a>
    <a href="2-3550.html">2</a>
    <a href="3-3550.html">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</p>

<p>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="1-5520.html">1</a>
    <a href="2-5520.html">2</a>
    <a href="3-5520.html">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</p>
```

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Ids within the document must be unique.

Comment: What I'm seeing straight away is that you have `id="myDropdown"` for all three div's. Your div IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to have unique ids for the divs. Something as simple as myDropDown1, myDropDown2, and myDropDown3 would work. You would need to modify myFunciton as well, something like this:

```
function myFunction(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).classList.toggle("show");
}
```

And your html could then look like:

```
    <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

    <p>
    <div class="dropdown">
       <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown1')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
       <div id="myDropdown1" class="dropdown-content">
         <a href="1-2160.html">1</a>
         <a href="2-2160.html">2</a>
         <a href="3-2160.html">3</a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </p>

    <p>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown2')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown2" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="1-3550.html">1</a>
    <a href="2-3550.html">2</a>
    <a href="3-3550.html">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</p>

<p>
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction('myDropdown3')" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown3" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="1-5520.html">1</a>
    <a href="2-5520.html">2</a>
    <a href="3-5520.html">3</a>
  </div>
</div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple elements with the same `id`. If you do, only the first one found in the document will be returned by `getElementById()`. So, your `click` handler:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Always references the first button.

But, as it turns out, you don't even need to use `id` to solve this issue.

Really, you are way over-doing this.

The `<p>` elements that wrap the `div` elements are unnecessary. They are semantically incorrect. If you want the extra vertical space they provide, just add `margin-bottom` to each of the `div` elements.

Now, you were setting a `click` event handling in the inline HTML as well as with `window.onclick`. Neither should be used. You should be setting up click event handlers on each button and then when each gets clicked, it can just toggle the visibility of the next element that comes after it. That will solve your issue.

Lastly, you also should be using `ul` and `li` elements here, because you are making lists, so to be semantically correct, use list elements when you make lists.

The very much simplified and working code is this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
}

// Get all the buttons as an array
var btns = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".dropbtn"));

// Loop through the array and assign click event handlers
btns.forEach(function(btn){
  btn.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

li {
  display:inline-block;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
.dropdown {
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="1-2160.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2-2160.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3-2160.html">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="1-3550.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2-3550.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3-3550.html">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="1-5520.html">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="2-5520.html">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="3-5520.html">3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```